# space decomposition to solve a nonsquare matrix to find null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix S of size m*n with column rank r. I’m looking for the null space matrix N which is a set of basis vectors for the equation SN=0. 
Is there any way to decompose the space of S to subspaces S_i, in which the null spaces N_i are orthogonal to each other? In other words, I’m looking for a hierarchical way to solve the equation SN=0. Can we find N_i in a way that they can form N?

Thank you so much in advance for any help on this.
Best, 
raha

Comment: Get the full singular value decomposition $S = U\Sigma V$ and pick the vectors that hit zeros in $V$ which is a basis for $N$.

Comment: thank you for your response! In my case m and n are large numbers... and I need the N vectors as an initialize set for another problem.. So I need to decompose S in a way that I can find N_i matrices which are related to each other in some cases ... Is there any way for such a space decomposition?

Comment: It would be like to decompose a matrix A to solve the equation Ax=b to find x,

Comment: Every subset of those columns of V is a subset of N